# WSL ubuntu 16.04 install virtualbox got error

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

```
my ubuntu version: 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I followed the below link to install the VirtualBox.
https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/

But after installation, I run `vboxmanage --version`, get some error message as picture below. How to fix it?

> error message: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1655
>   kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such
>   file or directory

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Are you using WSL in Windows?

Comment: @N0rbert yes.. is WSL in windows

Comment: Why not install VirtualBox for Windows then?

Comment: I think it should not work under WSL.

Comment: @Takkat coz i want to use bash command.. not window shell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WSL is a Linux subsystem that runs within the Windows kernel.  All the core modules that you seek in the Kernel don't actually exist within WSL, as the actual 'kernel' backend is really the Windows kernel and syscalls.

When installing something that needs kernel modules, you are more than likely going to run into an issue with it *because* there's no "pure linux kernel" involved here.

With regards to VirtualBox specifically, it exists for [Windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), too.  I would suggest you download VirtualBox for Windows, and install that in Windows.  Do **not** try and run VirtualBox or anything like that from within the WSL, it will almost certainly explode and not work properly for you.  Ever.  Instead, just put VBox on the Windows system that WSL is actually running within, because then it should 'behave' within the confines of Windows' restrictions of behavior.

(WSL is not actually a *full* Ubuntu, as a lot of the calls behind the scenes end up being intercepted and interpreted by Windows, not by a Linux kernel backend... so you can't really use it for virtualization, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The title of your link is "How to Install Oracle VirtualBox 5.2 on Ubuntu 17.10/16.04, Debian 9/8 " and not "How to Install Oracle VirtualBox 5.2 on WSL". Those instructions will NEVER work.

Oh and you can NOT install virtualbox on WSL. There is no support for it (well, at least not at this time; it is still evolving but I really doubt virtualbox is on the radar for WSL). Virtualbox for Ubuntu requires a Linux kernel and WSL does not have a Linux kernel. There is an emulation for a Windows kernel/subsystem that Virtualbox does not understand.

If you need virtualbox your only option is to install it in an actual operating system and then install an operating system in there. WSL is not an option.